# Using dplyr for multiple mutate on different criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my repex:

```
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 13:10:00", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 13:10:10", tz="UTC"), by="1 sec")
dates[dst(dates)] <- dates[dst(dates)] - 3600
datavalues <- data.frame(x=c(90,90,80,65,NA,64,71,75,62,63,74))
data <- cbind(dates,datavalues)
data

                 dates  x
1  2015-01-01 13:10:00 90
2  2015-01-01 13:10:01 90
3  2015-01-01 13:10:02 80
4  2015-01-01 13:10:03 65
5  2015-01-01 13:10:04 NA
6  2015-01-01 13:10:05 64
7  2015-01-01 13:10:06 71
8  2015-01-01 13:10:07 75
9  2015-01-01 13:10:08 62
10 2015-01-01 13:10:09 63
11 2015-01-01 13:10:10 74
```

I would have to obtain the following data frame (which I will concatenate to data):

```
results <- data.frame(Duration=c(3,3,3,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,1),Maxx=c(90,90,90,0,0,0,75,75,0,0,74),Delta=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,11))
results
   Duration Maxx Delta
1         3   90     0
2         3   90     0
3         3   90     0
4         0    0     0
5         0    0     0
6         0    0     0
7         2   75     7
8         2   75     0
9         0    0     0
10        0    0     0
11        1   74    11
```

I fix a threshold to 70.

- The Duration column is the number of consecutive times during exceeding the threshold.
- The Maxx column is the maximum of x for each non null duration.
- lastly the Delta column is the difference between the first x exceeding 70 and the precedent x.

I would like if possible to get code using dplyr because around this pice of code, there is already dplyr code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `data.table` `rleid` you can create group of consecutive values which are above or below the threshold and calculate the numbers in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

threshold <- 70

data %>%
  #Create a unique group of consecutive values
  group_by(group = rleid(replace(x, is.na(x), 0) < threshold)) %>% 
  #If the value is less than threshold put 0 in duration or else
  #include number of observations in the group. Do the same for max value.
  mutate(Duration = if_else(x < threshold, 0L, n(), missing = 0L), 
         #+(Duration > 0) is used to turn values less than threshold to 0
         Maxx = max(x, na.rm = TRUE) * +(Duration > 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #Subtract current value with previous value
  mutate(Delta = x - lag(x), 
         #Keep only those values that are first row in each group
         Delta = replace(Delta, group == lag(group, default = first(group)) | 
                                Duration == 0, 0)) %>%
  select(-group)


#   dates                   x Duration  Maxx Delta
#   <dttm>              <dbl>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2015-01-01 13:10:00    90        3    90     0
# 2 2015-01-01 13:10:01    90        3    90     0
# 3 2015-01-01 13:10:02    80        3    90     0
# 4 2015-01-01 13:10:03    65        0     0     0
# 5 2015-01-01 13:10:04    NA        0     0     0
# 6 2015-01-01 13:10:05    64        0     0     0
# 7 2015-01-01 13:10:06    71        2    75     7
# 8 2015-01-01 13:10:07    75        2    75     0
# 9 2015-01-01 13:10:08    62        0     0     0
#10 2015-01-01 13:10:09    63        0     0     0
#11 2015-01-01 13:10:10    74        1    74    11
```